# Recursive SSRS report in CRM 2011

Tags: recursion, reporting-services, parameters, dynamics-crm-2011, subreport

I have a report where all fields are clickable and all columns are potential parameters. When a field is clicked, the report reloads (as a sub-report if it were) with the added parameter.

for example, i have a list of items, their descriptions, sizes, color, etc. When I click "Gold" for color it will reload the report with the color parameter set to "Gold"

This report used to work fine in CRM 4. It all works fine in Visual studio and report manager but when I upload it to CRM 2011; it no longer works. The report runs smoothly when initially run but clicking a field in CRM does nothing, it doesn't even give me an error. the page flashes but the same data is visible.

I have another report with an actual sub-report that works fine. Is it the recursion that CRM hates? I can't set the parent report to itself, I'm assuming that is the problem. is there a way around this since it works in other Microsoft products?

Alternatively, could I use reportviewer.serverreport.setparameters to set the parameters of the report? Never used this before so I'm not sure if this works for CRM.

Comment: Are you using a Link action for the clicks to render the report with same report with parameters?

Comment: Hi lrb, I am. textbox properties -> action -> go to report -> same report.